# Modeling light transfer through every path with superpositioning

Tags: quantum-mechanics

So I asked a question about this topic earlier but since then, I did more digging into this problem.

Researchers at Berkeley experimented with a theory of photosynthesis happening using Quantum superposition. Basically, the absorbed electron travels through every single Chlorophyll, as opposed to random paths or the shortest path, to reach near 100% efficiency. The experiment is called 2D Fourier Transform Electronic Spectroscopy. They probed into the inner structure of the photosynthetic complex. They fired 3 successive pulses of laser light into it, which generated signals, which were then picked up by the detector.

My question/idea/early hypothesis is this: If I want to model this process in a circuit, would that look like a series of Hadamard gates?

Comment: Is there a paper to reference?

Comment: @UVphoton This video is pretty helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zc9Xk99gCr4

Answer (score 0):

The [paper](http://www.cchem.berkeley.edu/grfgrp/Papers/2007%20Engel%20Nature446.pdf) seems to think the process is analogous to Grover's Algorithm.

> When viewed in this way, the system is essentially performing
> a single quantum computation, sensing many states simultaneously
> and selecting the correct answer, as indicated by the efficiency of the energy transfer. In the presence of quantum coherence transfer, such an operation is analogous to Grover’s algorithm, with the hamiltonian describing both relaxation to the lowest energy state and coherence transfer (refilling the coherence lost from the transfer to the lowest-energy state)$^{27}$; such a scheme can provide efficiency beyond that of a classical search algorithm. This mechanism contrasts with a semiclassical ‘hopping’ mechanism through which the excitation moves stepwise from exciton state to exciton state, dissipating energy at each step, which would be similar to a classical search where only one state can be occupied at any one time.

From wikipedial it seem the quantum circuit would be something like:

[image: Grovers Algorithm from Wikipedia]

Comment: What is the Wikipedia entry? Just Grover's Algorithm?

Comment: @oo92  yes, it had the figure and some info about the algorithm  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm